# No implementation found for method setAccelerationSamplingPeriod on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/sensors/method

Tags: flutter, dart, missingmethodexception

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> setAccelerationSamplingPeriod on channel
> dev.fluttercommunity.plus/sensors/method) E/flutter (20167): #0
> MethodChannel._invokeMethod
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)

I'm not using any sensor plugin still I'm getting this error in my debug console... and also this report in Firebase crash analytics. This is not impacting in app.but still reporting in crashlytics.

I tried flutter clean, pub get, restart, uninstall, reinstall everything. but still not able to fix this.